# Is $d U = 0$ at thermodynamic equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

At thermodynamic equilibrium, there is thermal, mechanical, and diffusive equilibrium. Does this imply:

$$d\mu = dT = dV = 0$$

$$dU = TdS - PdV \implies dU = TdS$$

Here, I know entropy is maximum, so perhaps $dS=0$ and hence $dU = 0$? I also don't think I can write $d\mu = 0$ as this may be sort of abusive treating of the chemical potential.

Comment: If you are just sitting at equillibrium it would be surprising for anything to be changing, so $dX = 0$, for all $X$. None zero differentials impy change, which implies some sort of process is taking place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A system is in thermodynamic equilibrium when there are no changes in the macroscopic properties (internal energy, entropy, temperature, etc.) of the system.

So yes, at thermodynamic equilibrium $\Delta U=0$.

Hope this helps.